# call ajax inside wordpress posts/pages

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Sorry for this but I searched the whole web for a solution to my probleme but in vain :(

What I want to achieve is creating a normal Post and adding a form to it that once submitted, goes to a database and gets back a value.

I created a plugin for that and integrated it in the admin menu then set a function that queries the db :

```
myfunc_getcode($db, $table, $value, $return) // returns a value
```

how can I achieve this!?  I mean, when a user inserts some data in the form (that exists inside a post or page) then he clicks on submit, Ajax talks to the db and gets the results back.

I don't even know if wordpress 3.0.1 allows such things!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using

```
add_action('the_content', 'my_function');
```

this hooks my plugin to the posts and pages.

then in the function I transmit the content like;

```
function my_function($content) {}
```

Then I used Ajax by integrating jquery inside my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}
```

for submitting forms I used jquery/ajax to listen to the form

```
$("#my_form_id").submit(function() {
```

and used jquery's `$.post` to pass variables to a php page that handeles my results and returns them by echo.

hope this helps someone!